# nginx not matching very simple location

Tags: nginx

I have a stupid simple nginx configuration, and when run through https://nginx.viraptor.info/ it matches correctly. In production, however, I can't get location to match.

I'm trying to have the root of the site [www.site.com](http://www.site.com) AND [www.site.com/company/our-story](http://www.site.com/company/our-story) match and proxy to another server. Problem is root matches and /company does not.

My config snippet is here

Matches https://currentsite.com and redirects to https://differentsite.com

Does NOT match https://currentsite.com/company OR https://currentsite.com/comany/our-story on the "location /company" block like I expect. Instead falls through and doesn't direct.

```
   location = / {
       proxy_pass https://differentsite.com/;
       proxy_set_header Host differentsite.com;
    }

    location /company {
       proxy_pass https://differentsite.com/company;
       proxy_set_header Host differentsite.com;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
```

This must be the simplest location nginx question but I can't seem to make it work in actual production scenario.

Thanks

Comment: why are you using 2 location / modules?

Comment: Are you being redirected to a different URI that does not match the `location /company` block? You need to test this using `curl -I https://currentsite.com/company`

Comment: Using 2 locations because I got into a bind and need to proxy over to a low-code solution for our primay site, which also operates other apps under the same domain. I think this line solved it "proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;" although I must admit I have no idea why. Browser reported too many redirects.